# Vue: использует старые данные и не подставляет новые

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongodb, vuex

делаю проект на vue.js. при нажатии на кнопку - переходим на другую страницу, где получаем данные с базы по айди, который передаем. передается все правильно.
есть два варианта результатов: пустой, либо объект. если сначала переходим на объект - он кешируется и при следующем переходе, где уже должен быть пустой результат - выводит предыдущий объект, а не новый (пустой) результат.
как можно очистить данные? или как сделать так, чтобы компонент не подгружал предыдущие данные?
заранее спасибо

Comment: То есть переход происходит на две одинаковые ссылки с разным id, сервер возвращает два разных результата, но компонент продолжает отображать первый результат?

Answer (score 0):

не правильно организовала store: обработку результатов делала в action, вместо того, чтобы обработать полученные данные в getter, что влечет за собой ререндеринг